Odd Function/Integral when evaluating a Moment
I am studying the Laplace (Double Exponential) distribution, and I have the following quote from Siegrist, which is quite direct, and not bothered about conditions being fulfilled:

That the odd order moments are 0 follows from the symmetry of the distribution.

However, I have also been know that

All odd improper integrals are not equal to zero.

So what is applicable here? Is the textbook being informal? Is the odd integral condition not applicable here?
If I were to do this properly, would I need to check that the odd improper converged by splitting it at zero, and checking that each one was finite?
I am applying Calculus to probability. The question is not on this specific distribution only, but which ideas are important to retain (when moving from Calculus to Probability).
